# Question in regards to definition: finite dimensional

Tags: linear-algebra

Do we denote a vector space as finite dimensional IF it has a basis, or do we say that it is finite dimensional if it's associated through an isomorphic transformation with a "number space", ie. $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Also, are all number spaces, $\mathbb{R}^n$ finite dimensional?

Comment: All vector spaces have a basis.  A space is finite dimensional if it's basis is finite.  Yes, all $\mathbb{R}^n$ have finite dimension, specifically dimension $n$.

Answer (score 1):

A rigorous definition of a finite dimensional vector space might be:

> A vector space is **finite dimensional** if there exists a finite number of vectors that span that space.

You might go on to prove that there is a well-defined minimum number of vectors that span a finite dimensional space, and we call this number the *dimension* of the space. In particular, any two bases for the same space have the same cardinality.

Answer (score 1):

- Do we denote a vector space as finite dimensional IF it has a basis?

No. A vector space is finite-dimensional if it has a *finite* basis. An infinite dimensional vector space may (@Seth tells me *must*) have a basis. For example the polynomials in $x$ have a basis $1, x, x^2 \ldots \ $ .

- ... or do we say that it is finite dimensional if it's associated
  through an isomorphic transformation with a "number space", ie.
  $\mathbb{R}^n$?

No. There are many vector spaces that have nothing to do with numbers. Even within numbers, you can restrict reals to rationals and you still have a vector space.

- Also, are all number spaces, $\mathbb{R}^n$ finite dimensional?

Yes. They have, as @Seth says, dimension $n$.

Comment: One might add that if a real vector space is finite dimensional, then it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ for some $n$.

Comment: @Thomas One might indeed.